# How to make Vimeo embed full screen?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a vimeo embed that I want to cover the entire screen. However setting `width` or `min-width` to 100vw makes the video smaller.

Here is a snippet demonstrating the problem:

```css
#test{
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}
#testvideo{
   width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
     <iframe id="testvideo" title="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/644036051?h=b260a3b1b0" frameborder="0"   allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set an `aspect-ratio` on the `<iframe>`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#testvideo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="testvideo" title="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/644036051?h=b260a3b1b0" frameborder="0"   allowfullscreen></iframe>
```